# Problem saving data using Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I'm

I'm building a website on Ruby On Rails 3.0.7 and I want to save a `store` object and its `languages`. So, I have the following models:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :languages, :through => :store_languages
  has_many :store_languages

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :store_languages

  #Validations
  validates :title, :presence => true, :length => 5..100
  validates :contact_email, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i }
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores, :through => :store_languages
  has_many :store_languages
end

class StoreLanguage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :language

  validates :store_id, :presence => true
  validates :language_id, :presence => true
end
```

StoresController's relevant actions:

```
  def new
    @store = Store.new
    @store.store_languages.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @store }
    end
  end

  # POST /stores
  # POST /stores.xml
  def create
    #raise params.inspect
    @store = current_user.stores.new(params[:store])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @store.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@store, :notice => 'Store was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @store, :status => :created, :location => @store }
      else
        @store.store_languages.build
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @store.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

View: /stores/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@store) do |f| %>
  <% if @store.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@store.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this store from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @store.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <label for="title">Title*</label><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="description">Description</label><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="contact_email">Contact E-mail*</label><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contact_email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="logo">Logo</label><br />
    <%= f.file_field :logo %>
  </p>

    <% f.fields_for :store_languages do |lf| %>

      <%= lf.collection_select :language_id, @languages, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true } %>
    <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So, I've got the following records in the `languages` table:

```
 id |   name
 3    English
 4    Español
```

What happens is that when I create a new store selecting the two languages from the list, it will save the following at the `store_languages` table:

id | store_id | language_id
 4       4          1

And the language_id = 1 doesn't exist.

If I debug the application at the `create` action, I get the following:

```
"store"=>{"title"=>"asdasdsdsadasdasdasd", "description"=>"", "contact_email"=>"asdasdsa@asdasdsad.com", "logo"=>"", "store_languages_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"language_id"=>["3", "4"]}}}
```

You can see that the ids are correct here: 3 and 4. So, I don't know why it saves 1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <%= lf.collection_select :language_ids, @languages, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true } %>
```

(ie using `ids` instead of `id` in the attribute name)

Comment: I get the following error when I try that: undefined method `language_ids' for #<StoreLanguage id: nil, store_id: nil, language_id: nil. Thanks anyway.